# Virtual Inheritance without Explicitly Initializing a Parent Class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have two class Machine and Human that virtually inherit from atom. Now I write a class called "Cyborg", and want to initialize Atom from Cyborg. The code is

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Atom {
public:
  Atom(size_t t): transformium(t) {};
private:
  const size_t transformium;
};

class Human : public virtual Atom {
public:
  Human(string name) : Atom(-1), name(name) {}
protected:
  string name;
};

class Machine : public virtual Atom {
public:
  Machine() {}
  Machine(int id) : id(id) {}
protected:
  int id;
};

class Cyborg : public Human, public Machine {
public:
  Cyborg(string name, int id) : Atom(0), Human(name) {}
};

int main() {
  Cyborg cyborg("robocup", 911);
  return 0;
}
```

However, the CXX compiler requires Machine to initialize Atom, because of the const member "transformium".

```
error: constructor for 'Machine' must explicitly initialize the base class 'Atom' which does not have a default constructor
```

Comment: I would challenge your object decomposition. Neither Humans nor Machines are Atoms (IS-A relationship). They have Atoms (HAS-A relationship) and probably shouldn't inherit from Atoms. Whenever I see diamond inheritance, I start looking for improper decomposition.

Comment: @Rob. Agreed. Humans have electrons as well :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the compiler error suggests, you must explicitly initialize the base class `Atom` in the constructors of `Machine`.

The reason for this is that you can create an instance of `Machine`. For such an object, there has to be a way to properly initialize the `Atom` part of `Machine`.

**Update**

`Atom` is initialized differently depending on whether you create an instance of `Human`, `Machine`, or `Cyborg`. Here's an updated version of your code, with a bit of explanation thrown in.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Atom {
   public:
      Atom(size_t t): transformium(t) { std::cout << "Came to Atom::Atom()\n"; }
   private:
      const size_t transformium;
};

class Human : public virtual Atom {
   public:
      Human(string name) : Atom(-1), name(name) {}
      // Atom(-1) is ignored when an instance of Cyborg is created
      // but not when an instance of Human is created.
   protected:
      string name;
};

class Machine : public virtual Atom {
   public:
      Machine(int id) : id(id), Atom(-1) {}
      // Atom(-1) is ignored when an instance of Cyborg is created
      // but not when an instance of Machine is created.
   protected:
      int id;
};

class Cyborg : public Human, public Machine {
   public:
      Cyborg(string name, int id) : Atom(0), Human(name), Machine(id) {}
      // Atom needs to be intialized here since it won't be initialized 
      // in either Human or Machine.
};

int main() {
   Cyborg cyborg("robocup", 911); // Calls Atom::Atom() only once.
   std::cout << "------------------\n";
   Human human("robocup");        // Calls Atom::Atom() once.
   std::cout << "------------------\n";
   Machine machine(911);          // Calls Atom::Atom() once.
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Came to Atom::Atom()
------------------
Came to Atom::Atom()
------------------
Came to Atom::Atom()
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, Machine and Human share the same parent class "Atom". Therefore, Atom only needs to be initialized once. Is it possible to do that only in Human class, not Machine?